# Why is nginx duplicating the folder in the path

Tags: linux, nginx, adminer

I am trying to configure Adminer with Nginx. This is my adminer.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  location /adminer {
    root /usr/share/webapps/adminer;
    index index.php;
  }
}
```

However, when I go to `localhost/adminer` I get the error `/usr/share/webapps/adminer/adminer/index.php is not found (No such file or directory)`.

The `adminer` folder is duplicated and I don't know why. The location should resolve to `/usr/share/webapps/adminer/index.php`.

Comment: Check the difference between [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) nginx directives.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thanks, `alias` was what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location should just be

- `/` from `/usr/share/webapps/adminer` for `localhost`
- `/adminer` from `/usr/share/webapps` for `localhost/adminer`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  location /adminer {
    root /usr/share/webapps/;
    index index.php;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... this worked.. first time using nginx... what if I wanted to set the location to `/test` for `localhost/test`. Nginx always seems to include `test` as part of the directory but I just want it as part of the URL and not part of the root directory.

Comment: Nevermind, the `alias` keyword answered my question above.

Comment: Not to worryl everyone's first time for something, and nginx takes some unusual mindset!.. often you want to create your own `nginx.conf`, while the default one will [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) many files from its location in `/etc/`, which can bring in paths you don't expect or without it lose some mimetype filtering, etc. you want to support .. I've never used `alias`, but it's probably what you're after if it works!